# SQL Server: PIVOT data stored in multiple rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a data that is stored in this way:

```
ID|Text     |A_ID
--+---------+-------
01|WestPC   |4
01|Win7     |5
01|i3-3240  |6
02|EastPC   |4
02|WinXP    |5
02|i5-6500  |6
```

and i need to pivot it to obtain this:

```
ID|4      |5    |6
--+-------+-----+--------
01|WestPC |Win7 |i3-3240
02|EastPC |WinXP|i5-6500
```

so far, I've come to this code:

```
with ComputerData as (
    SELECT ID,Text,A_ID
    FROM MyTable
)

Select ID,[4],[5],[6]
from (
    select ID,A_ID,Text
    from ComputerData 
) c
PIVOT 
(
    Text
    FOR A_ID in (4,5,6)
) P;
```

but it is not working.. what I'm doing wrong (all SQL Server tells me is I got a syntax error, but I can't understand which one).. can someone please help me?
Many thanks!

Comment: Well....your select statement is not doing what you think it is. SELCT ID,4,5,6 is selecting those values as integers. You don't have a column A_ID in the qubquery you have aliased as "c".

Comment: 1) Please [edit] your question title to something descriptive of the actual problem. Most of what you've used is simple and useless repetition of the tag information, and if you remove those your  title is *Problems with*, which coveys absolutely no information.Your title should be clear and descriptive enough  to be useful to someone in the future who is seeing it in a list of search results. 2) If SQL Server gave you a *syntax error*, it also gave you an error message. It's helpful if you include that **exact** message in your post. Please add it when you're making the [edit] to your title.

Comment: Edited. As I said, the error was pretty uninteresting:
Incorrect syntax near '4'.

Comment: As you say, the syntax error was that I was not enclosing numbers in square brackets :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when a_id = 4 then text end) as [4],
       max(case when a_id = 5 then text end) as [5],
       max(case when a_id = 6 then text end) as [6]
from mytable
group by id;
```

Your specific problem is probably the lack of escape characters around "4", "5", and "6".  SQL interprets them as numbers.

Comment: MANY Thanks! never tought of using conditional aggregation. Compared on a test set of 100K rows, it is roughly 50% faster than PIVOT.. 
Concern: MAX will slow the query down? grouping by ID, it will search for a MAX value over 1 value, so it should be trivial.. yet, could it possibly be faster?

Comment: @Aldo . . . I don't understand your comment.  You observe that this is faster, then you are concerned about performance.  The overhead for `MAX()` is trivial compared to the aggregation needed for the `GROUP BY` or `PIVOT` solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you still want the PIVOT.  Personally, I prefer the conditional aggregation.  It allows for a bit more flexibility.

**Example**

```
with ComputerData as (
    SELECT ID,Text,A_ID
    FROM MyTable
)
Select *
 From  ComputerData src
 Pivot (max([Text]) for A_ID in ([4],[5],[6]) ) P
```

**Returns**

```
ID  4       5       6
01  WestPC  Win7    i3-3240
02  EastPC  WinXP   i5-6500
```

Comment: Works perfectly, ad the conditional aggregation. But on my test on 100K rows, CA is roughly 50% faster than PIVOT.

So if I understand correctly, I can't simply PIVOT for [Text], but I need to PIVOT for a function on [Text].. why?